# Android Bluemix not showing speaker tag

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I am using IBM bluemix to transcribe some audio, and I want to use the APIs speaker recognition.

I set up the the recognizer like this:

```
private RecognizeOptions getRecognizeOptions() {
    return new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
            .continuous(true)
            .contentType(ContentType.OPUS.toString())
            //.model("en-US")
            .model("en-US_BroadbandModel")
            .timestamps(true)
            .smartFormatting(true)
            .interimResults(true)
            .speakerLabels(true)
            .build();
}
```

But the returned JSON doesnt include the speaker tag. How can I get the speaker tag also returned with the bluemix java API?

My audio recorder in Android looks like this:

```
private void recordMessage() {
    //mic.setEnabled(false);
    speechService = new SpeechToText();
    speechService.setUsernameAndPassword("usr", "pwd");
    if(listening != true) {
        capture = new MicrophoneInputStream(true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                try {
                    speechService.recognizeUsingWebSocket(capture, getRecognizeOptions(), new MicrophoneRecognizeDelegate());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    showError(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
        Log.v("TAG",getRecognizeOptions().toString());
        listening = true;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Listening....Click to Stop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        try {
            capture.close();
            listening = false;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Stopped Listening....Click to Start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant that he should add the speech-to-text tag, not text-to-speech ;)

Comment: @bear what's the audio file and the recognize method you are using? are you using WebSockets?

Comment: @GermanAttanasio I'm using the watson Android audio streaming api, see my updated code snippet

Comment: What version of the java-sdk are you using?

Comment: @GermanAttanasio I'm using 1.8

Comment: @bear the `watson-developer-cloud-java-sdk` version.

Comment: is what you mean the com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:android-sdk:0.2.3 ? where can i find which watson-developer-cloud-java-sdk im using?

Comment: @GermanAttanasio: ping, bear had answered

Comment: I don't know Android that much.

Comment: @GermanAttanasio do you have any idea on how to solve it in a non-Android Java environment?

Comment: Yes, I would use the java-sdk 3.8.0 with the code you have above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example I wrote a sample application and got the speaker labels to work.

Make sure you are using the [Java-SDK 4.2.1](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/releases/tag/java-sdk-4.2.0). In your `build.gradle` add

```
compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:4.2.1'
```

Here is the snippet of code that recognizes a [WAV file](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-nodejs/raw/master/public/audio/english3.g712.wav) from the `assets` folder using WebSockets, interim results, and speaker label.

```
RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
  .contentType("audio/wav")
  .model(SpeechModel.EN_US_NARROWBANDMODEL.getName())
  .interimResults(true)
  .speakerLabels(true)
  .build();

SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("SPEECH-TO-TEXT-USERNAME", "SPEECH-TO-TEXT-PASSWORD");

InputStream audio = loadInputStreamFromAssetFile("speaker_label.wav");

service.recognizeUsingWebSocket(audio, options, new BaseRecognizeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onTranscription(SpeechResults speechResults) {
        Assert.assertNotNull(speechResults);
        System.out.println(speechResults.getResults().get(0).getAlternatives().get(0).getTranscript());
        System.out.println(speechResults.getSpeakerLabels());
    }
});
```

Where `loadInputStreamFromAssetFile()` is:

```
public static InputStream loadInputStreamFromAssetFile(String fileName){
  AssetManager assetManager = getAssets(); // From Context
  try {
    InputStream is = assetManager.open(fileName);
    return is;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
}
```

Application logs:

```
I/System.out: so how are you doing these days 
I/System.out: so how are you doing these days things are going very well glad to hear 
I/System.out: so how are you doing these days things are going very well glad to hear I think I mentioned 
I/System.out: so how are you doing these days things are going very well glad to hear I think I mentioned before that there's a company now that I'm 
I/System.out: so how are you doing these days things are going very well glad to hear I think I mentioned before that there's a company now that I'm working with which is very much 
I/System.out: so how are you doing these days things are going very well glad to hear I think I mentioned before that there's a company now that I'm working with which is very much just just myself and Chris now 
I/System.out: so how are you doing these days things are going very well glad to hear I think I mentioned before that there's a company now that I'm working with which is very much just just myself and Chris now you had mentioned that %HESITATION okay 
I/System.out: so how are you doing these days things are going very well glad to hear I think I mentioned before that there's a company now that I'm working with which is very much just just myself and Chris now you had mentioned that %HESITATION okay 
I/System.out: [{
I/System.out:   "confidence": 0.487,
I/System.out:   "final": false,
I/System.out:   "from": 0.03,
I/System.out:   "speaker": 0,
I/System.out:   "to": 0.34
I/System.out: }, {
I/System.out:   "confidence": 0.487,
I/System.out:   "final": false,
I/System.out:   "from": 0.34,
I/System.out:   "speaker": 0,
I/System.out:   "to": 0.54
I/System.out: }, {
I/System.out:   "confidence": 0.487,
I/System.out:   "final": false,
I/System.out:   "from": 0.54,
I/System.out:   "speaker": 0,
I/System.out:   "to": 0.63
I/System.out: }, {
...... blah blah blah
I/System.out: }, {
I/System.out:   "confidence": 0.343,
I/System.out:   "final": false,
I/System.out:   "from": 13.39,
I/System.out:   "speaker": 1,
I/System.out:   "to": 13.84
I/System.out: }]
```